# Sql Server Standard 2014: Reindex job locked by other transactions

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index, locking

On a customer of ours we have `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)` installed. It's a heavy transactions schema (especially during nights) and we have a scheduled `REINDEX` maintenance job that runs every early morning at 4 am.

We have noted that tonight the reindex job got stuck for like 45minutes on a `alter index` on a particular table because it was locked by another transaction (an `UPDATE` statement issued by a user, a very common transaction for our system).

The guy responsible for the night check promprly killed the transactions (reindex included) since we were already receiving complaints from the users; when he killed it the current `ALTER INDEX` statement was blocked by 45 minutes, but the entire `REINDEX` job took at that moment almost 4 hours (he killed it at 7:51 am).

Is there a way to avoid the `REINDEX` job to get blocked by other transactions?

EDIT: the fragmentation levels we noted (< 30%) showed that we could probably go for a `REORGANIZE` instead of a `REINDEX` thus eliminating the chance of *other transactions being locked by the reorganize*, but the reorganize itself could still be blocked.

Comment: Consider using REORGANIZE + UPDATE STATISTICS. For your case that two operation seem convenient. The REORGANIZE operation is resumable, so even it would blocked and stopped, it could be run from the stop point. UPDATE STATISTICS is, maybe, the most important difference between REBUILD and REORGANIZE operations - to make REORGANIZE be as close to REBUILD as possible you should perform it.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2014 are you using? If it's Enterprise, you can try rebuilding your indexes online using the WITH(ONLINE=ON) clause.

Comment: Sadly it's the standard edition. We are currently evaluating Ola Hallengren rebuild script with a timeout parameter to skip the locked tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and we have a scheduled REINDEX maintenance job that runs every early morning at 4 am.

Wait..is that really necessary to run the reindex job *every* day ?. Do you even look at whether the indexes are fragmented ?. Since you said its a critical system I will take liberty of assuming the underlying storage is fast that further lowers the possibility of re-indexing everyday. Please think about it.

> Is there a way to avoid the REINDEX job to get blocked by other transactions?

If you absolutely want this, then run index maintenance during downtime or when load is relatively very very less and no DML operations are going on. You can use online index rebuild ( If you have enterprise edition) but that also takes lock and *may* be blocked. Plus frequently rebuilding index out dates stats more often leading to more compilations

Suggestion: Use [Ola Hallengren Index rebuild](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) solution.

Comment: Tnx for your reply. I'm not the DBA but I work very closely, so I can tell you that from a preliminary check done in the morning on the fragmentation level it looks like that it is less than 30%. This would suggest a REORGANIZE instead of a reindex, but that could be locked too. the customer doesn't have an Enterprise license, only Standard. The fact we do it every night is due to the fact that it takes place AFTER some DML intesive batch operations done during night.

Comment: The thing is simple, if something is accessing the table that is being rebuilt it may be blocked. That is why people normally schedule index related job on weekends

Comment: Yes, we used to have them on the weekends but moved them everyday since we saw too much fragmentation. It should be noted that even during weekend nights and day the transactions are heavy anyway (more in night than day)

Comment: Tnx for the Ola script reference. We're currently exploring using that one since has a timeout setting as well.

Comment: @frankieta Yes Ola's script is really worth.I would also like to add that with more fast storage coming the whole concept of index fragmentation would soon go out of picture. Ex in Azure SQL Database their is hardly any need to rebuild indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have single spinning disks as storage? If so, you might see possible advantages from defrag. If you have more modern storage, then is is likely that you defrag but only see marginal benefits from the hassle. I've written three blog posts on this, I suggest you start with the last one: http://sqlblog.karaszi.com/fragmentation-the-final-installment/

If you *do* insist on defrag, you might want to focus on page fullness instead. Ola's scripts isn't written that way, though.

Also, updating statistics has potential from being far more useful then index defrag, and is way less costly. Consider using example from Ola's site in a job, where you only update the stats, where at least 1 row has been modified since last update of stats.

Comment: The customer has two disks, one for log file and one for data file, and they are HDDs (Enterprise but not SSDs).